# ShrinkWrap load libraries from POM for JavaArchive

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, shrinkwrap

I am working on multi maven module project. And I am writing unit tests using Arquillian.
Till now every thing is fine, as I am adding dependencies in my test class from my module and other dependent module as well.

Example:

```
.addPackages(true, "com.test.pk2")  
.addPackages(true, "com.test.pk1")
```

like so.

In order to simplify my unit tests, I am using Shrink Wrap Maven dependency resolver.

```
File[] crLibs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().asFile();
```

But I ran into some of the issues:

1. I could not able to merge Java Archives to my final archive, and the final archive is not unable to deploy.
2. I do not find much support for Java Archives.
3. If I try to add jar files to final archive, I ran into java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError.

Am I missing any thing or what is wrong with this.
Can any one help with this?

More Info on Technologies:
ShrinkWrap 2.0.0
Glassfish 3.1.2.2
Maven2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaArchive[] dependencies = Maven.configureResolver().offline().loadPomFromFile(POM).importRuntimeDependencies()
            .resolve().withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
```

I solved this way. And it is working now.